# Сумма арифметической прогрессии

Tags: java, математика

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scanner.nextInt(); // количество сумм,которые надо вывести
    
    for ( int x = 0; x<i; x++ ) {
        int A = scanner.nextInt(); // первое значение арифметической прогрессии 
        int B = scanner.nextInt(); // её шаг
        int N = scanner.nextInt(); // количество членов прогрессии 
        int SUM = ( ( 2*A + B*(N-1) ) / 2) * N; // формула для расчета суммы арифметической прогрессии 

        System.out.print(SUM + " ");
    }
}
}
```

Задания: даются определенные значение, и код должен выводить суммы арифметических прогрессий.
Во время теста,некоторые значения получаются неверными.
Как можно исправить?

Например, входные данные

- 10 
  24 15 77 
  27 16 56 
  5 8 70 
  2 4 56 
  1 8 59 
  10 19 88 
  28 0 30 
  27 0 78 
  30 18 84 
  24 12 28

мой ответ:
45738 26152 19670 6272 13747 73568* 840 2106 65268 5208

ожидаемый:
45738 26152 19670 6272 13747 73612* 840 2106 65268 5208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала множить на N, а потом делить на 2...

```
int SUM = N*(2*A + B*(N-1))/2;
```

Проблема в том, что `B*(N-1)` может быть нечетно, и при *целочисленном* делении на 2 вы получите неверный ответ.